# Error de Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un formulario para devolver productos en PHP, pero me esta dando el error de Call to a member function query() on null, y no entiendo donde está el problema.

Por un lado está el archivo "DevuelveProductos":

```
<?php
require "conexion2.php";
class DevuelveProductos extends Conexion{
    public function DevuelveProductos(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    
    public function get_productos(){
        $resultado=$this->$conexion_db->query('SELECT * FROM productos');
        $productos=$resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $productos;
    }
}
?>
```

El codigo para conectarse a la BD es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require "config.php";
class Conexion{
    protected $conexion_db;
    
    public function Conexion(){
        $this->conexion_db=new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_CONTRA, DB_NOMBRE);
        if($this->conexion_db->connect_errno){
            echo "Fallo al conectar MySql: " . $this->conexion_db->connect_error;
            return;
        }
        
        $this->conexion_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);
    }
}
?>

<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');
define('DB_CONTRA', '');
define('DB_NOMBRE', 'pruebas');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, porque hace dias que estoy con eso, y no le encuentro la solución.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que estas heredando la conexión ```$this->$conexion_db```? Sería mejor que también añades tu clase conexión.

Comment: Si, estoy heredando la conexión. Acabo de editar mi pregunta de arriba para que se puedan ver los archivos de conexion a BD

Comment: Estas haciendo $this->$conexion_db para apuntar a una variable variable, ya probaste en  apuntar solo a la variable $this->conexion_db?

Comment: Fíjate lo que te dice Julio Guerrero, que lo acabo de ver también, aparte mira estas lineas ```public function Conexion(){}``` y ```public function DevuelveProductos(){}``` cámbialo por ```public function __construct() {}``` y llamas a la función ```get_productos()``` para obtener resultado.

Comment: Cambié lo que me dijo DBE pero sigo con el mismo error

Comment: quedó algo asi: public function __construct(){
   $this->get_productos();
  }

Comment: Tienes que dejar el código tal cual lo tienes, solo cambia la línea que te mencione, y  para llamar a la función debes instanciar el objeto y luego accedes a la función, algo como: ```$obj = new DevuelveProductos(); $data = $obj->get_productos();```

Comment: Hola, muestra el contexto donde usas tu clase `DevuelveProductos`. Si analizas bien, la conexión se estaría creando en el método `Conexion()` de tu clase `Conexion`, ¿acaso llamas a ese método en alguna parte? No vemos el contexto, y no lo sabemos. Dicho eso, deberías considerar una mejor organización de tu código, creo que ese es el mayor problema aquí, aparte de lo que ya te dijeron, en las clases los campos no estáticos deben llamarse así: `$this->campoNoEstatico`, no usas `$` en el campo, sino en `$this`

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en tu código, te dejo un posible ejemplo.

El primer fallo es como ha mencionado Julio Guerrero, estas llamando a tu conexión como una variable y no como objeto `$this->$conexion_db` debería ser `$this->conexion_db`.

El segundo fue cambiar `public function Conexion(){}` y `DevuelveProductos(){}` por `public function __construct( ) {}`

**Ejemplo:**

*Conexion.php*

```
<?php
// Datos conexion
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');
define('DB_CONTRA', '');
define('DB_NOMBRE', 'pruebas');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

class Conexion{

    protected object $conexion_db;
    
    public function __construct( ) {
        // Creas la conexion
        $this->conexion_db=new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_CONTRA, DB_NOMBRE);
        // Charset utf8
        $this->conexion_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);

        // Compruebas conexion
        if($this->conexion_db->connect_errno){
            echo "Fallo al conectar MySql: " . $this->conexion_db->connect_error;
            return;
        }
    }

    # Podrías crear más funciones, uno por ejemplo seria obtener datos, etc...
}
```

*DevuelveProductos*

```
<?php
require_once "Conexion.php";
class DevuelveProductos extends Conexion{
   
    public function __construct( 
        private array $productos = [], // Datos a retornar
    )
    {
        parent::__construct();        
    }
    
    /**
     * Retornar datos obtenidos
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function displayProducto() :array
    {
        return $this->get_productos();
    }

    /**
     * Obtener datos desde BD
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    private function get_productos() :array
    {
        $resultado = $this->conexion_db->query('SELECT * FROM productos');
        
        if ($resultado) $this->productos = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        else return [];
        // Retornas datos
        return $this->productos;
    }
}
```

Para llamar a tus productos haces algo como:

```
// Esta parte de codigo lo añades donde quieres obtener los datos
//
// Incluyes la clase 
require_once "DevuelveProductos.php";
// Instancias objeto
$obj = new DevuelveProductos(); 
// Obtienes datos como array
$data = $obj->displayProducto();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```